# Can we subclass NSOperationQueue?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to subclass NSOperationQueue to track Internet dependent operations are successfully finished or not. Is it possible to subclass NSOperationQueue?

Comment: Yes you can do it

Comment: You can, but you don't have to.  Instead, you can create a class which observes all operations added to a queue.  Composition is usually preferred to inheritance.

Comment: Perhaps we could help you more if you explained why do you want to subclass `NSOperationQueue` and we can probably help you tackle that broader problem. But while subclassing `NSOperation` is not uncommon, but it's pretty rare to subclass `NSOperationQueue`. (And Apple's own demonstration of subclassing `NSOperationQueue` is a bit of a hot mess, IMHO.) So, I'd take a hard look at the broader objective before I jumped into subclassing `NSOperationQueue`.

Comment: Basically, I would like to know when all operations are finished executing their job. Based on all operations are done i have to take certain actions. So if i can subclass the NSOperationQueue i can customise by adding variables and methods on it.

Comment: You generally accomplish that by creating a "completion" `NSOperation`, and then as you add operations to your queue, do `[completionOperation addDependency:operation]`, in effect making that `completionOperation` dependent upon all the other operations. Then, when you're done adding all of those operations, add that `completionOperation` (with all of its dependencies) to the queue. No `NSOperationQueue` subclass is needed.

Answer (score -2):

You can very well subclass NSOperationQueue.

Below is an example of sub classing OperationQueue

```
import Foundation
    class AsynchronousOperation: Operation {
        override var isAsynchronous: Bool { return true }
        override var isExecuting: Bool { return state == .executing }
        override var isFinished: Bool { return state == .finished }

        var state = State.ready {
            willSet {
                willChangeValue(forKey: state.keyPath)
                willChangeValue(forKey: newValue.keyPath)
            }
            didSet {
                didChangeValue(forKey: state.keyPath)
                didChangeValue(forKey: oldValue.keyPath)
            }
        }

        enum State: String {
            case ready = "Ready"
            case executing = "Executing"
            case finished = "Finished"
            fileprivate var keyPath: String { return "is" + self.rawValue }
        }

        override func start() {
            if self.isCancelled {
                state = .finished
            } else {
                state = .ready
                main()
            }
        }

        override func main() {
            if self.isCancelled {
                state = .finished
            } else {
                state = .executing
            }
        }
    }
```

How to use:
 1. Call `super.main()` when override `main` method, call `super.start()` when override `start` method.
 2. When operation is finished or cancelled set `self.state = .finished'`

For more details refer to this [link](https://gist.github.com/Sorix/57bc3295dc001434fe08acbb053ed2bc)

Comment: That's not subclassing `NSOperationQueue`. That's subclassing `NSOperation`. And he was asking about Objective-C, not Swift.

Comment: Also, FYI, Apple suggests synchronizing your `Operation` property changes. The above is not thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks! but thats not NSOperationQueue. Subclassing NSOperation is common as everybody us do so.